# How can i give pager to drupal_add_tabledrag

Tags: php, javascript, drupal, module

i am using the function drupal_add_tabledrag. Now i want pager also in that. Is there any option?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That won't work, tabledrag will only work if all items are on the same page. Adding a pager is illogical as it will become impossible to manage the weights of the items when spread over 2 or more pages.

Comment: Then, why the taxonomy module can achieve that? In admin/structure/taxonomy/[vocabulary] interface, you can drag & drop terms and when there are more than 100 items (terms), the content is split into pages.

Answer (score 1):

drupal_add_tabledrag is js script, work with special form elements and doesn't depend on pager_query.